# Dynamic form select field data update in database in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

I have a select field in my form, and the options in this select field are dynamically populated from a user table. The values of these options correspond to the 'author_id' in the user table. Now, what I want to achieve is that when a user selects an option, the 'author_nickname' from the user table for the selected 'author_id' should be updated in the 'author_nickname' column of the 'posts' table.

I've already written some code for this, but it's not working. This project is built on CodeIgniter 4. Can anyone help me with this?

**View Form Code**

```
<form method="post" action="<?= site_url('admin/posts/update/' . $post['id']); ?>" id="your_form_id">
   <!-- Author Select -->
   <label for="author">Author:</label>
   <select id="author" name="author_id">
      <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
      <option value="<?= $author['author_id']; ?>" <?= ($author['author_id'] == $post['author_id']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
         <?= $author['author_name']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
</form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
<?php
// app/Controllers/PostController.php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\PostModel;
use App\Models\CategoryModel;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    protected $postModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postModel = new PostModel();
        $this->categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
        $this->userModel = new UserModel();
    }

    public function postList()
    {
        $posts = $this->postModel->findAll();
        foreach ($posts as &$post) {
            $post["category_names"] = explode(",", $post["category_names"]);
        }
        return view("admin/posts/posts_list", ["posts" => $posts]);
    }

    // ----------Post Edit Code------------

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $model = new PostModel();
        $post = $model->find($id);

        if ($post) {
            // Retrieve the list of authors
            $authorModel = new UserModel();
            $authors = $authorModel->findAll();

            if ($this->request->getMethod() === "post") {
                // Get the selected author_id from the form
                $selectedAuthorId = $this->request->getPost("author_id");

                // Find the selected author by author_id
                $author = $authorModel->find($selectedAuthorId);

                if ($author) {
                    // Update the 'author_id' and 'author_nickname' fields in the post
                    $updatedData = [
                        "author_id" => $selectedAuthorId,
                        "author_nickname" => $author["author_nickname"],
                    ];

                    // Update the post in the database
                    $model->update($id, $updatedData);

                    return redirect()
                        ->to(site_url("admin/posts/postList"))
                        ->with("success", "Post updated successfully");
                } else {
                    return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->withInput()
                        ->with("error", "Invalid author selected");
                }
            }

            return view("admin/posts/post_edit", [
                "post" => $post,
                "authors" => $authors,
            ]);
        } else {
            return redirect()
                ->to(site_url("admin/posts/postList"))
                ->with("error", "Post not found");
        }
    }

    // ----------Post Update Code------------

    public function update($id)
    {
        $model = new PostModel();
        $postData = $this->request->getPost();
        $model->update($id, $postData);

        return redirect()
            ->to(site_url("admin/posts/postList"))
            ->with("success", "Post updated successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but when I go to my database in phpMyAdmin and look at the 'posts' table, only the 'author_id' is getting updated, but the 'author_nickname' is not getting updated

Comment: My suggestion is to create an SQL query you know works and then migrate it into CI code - I still use that fairly often and will help you spot any errors.